# micronaut sending 'connection: close' for all response code > 499

Tags: micronaut, httpconnection

It was discovered that micronaut is sending a response header `connection: close` when the front door response code is > 499 (299 for 1.3.7). This causing the caller to close the connection and create a new one which is not desired. We are using `502` to indicate a failed required backend and this would result in a `connection: close` with this new change. One option is to manually set `connection: keep-alive` for any such exception scenarios.

Here is a link to the code in question: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/ee842bd1e1b62b8a49a971fead4e076a7d9a0b7b/http-server-netty/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/server/netty/RoutingInBoundHandler.java#L1712

Is there any better way to handle this scenario ?